# Prove that a certain sequence of partial sums (involving integrals) converge.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I have to prove the following:

Define $\gamma_{n}= 1+1/2+1/3+...+1/n-\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{t}dt$.Prove that $\{\gamma_{n}\}$ converge.

I need your help because I don't know how to involve the algebra of integrable functions to prove this. I was thinking to do this by definition of convergence of a sequence, but I am sure that this is not a good way and I think that there is a better way to prove this using the integration theory, but I don't know how. Can you help me to prove this, I apreciate your help.

Comment: Are you sure ?.

Comment: Ok let me check :), I stay in the discussion even when I am searching in that question :)

Comment: Well I think it doesn't help very much because I am looking for a formal proof, I think is good but I want to look at new ideas thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed as follows:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
  \gamma_n &=& \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} -\int_1^n \frac{d t}{t} = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{k} -\int_{k}^{k+1} \frac{d t}{t} \right) + \int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t} \\ &=& \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+t} \right) \mathrm{d}t + \int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Note that each term above is positive, hence $\gamma_n > 0$ and $\gamma_n$ is the increasing sequence. Since for all $ 0 \leqslant t \leqslant 1$ we have $ \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+t} \leqslant \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}$
$$
   \gamma_n \leqslant \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right) + \frac{1}{n} \stackrel{\mathrm{telescopes}}{=} 1 - \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n} = 1 + \frac{1}{n(n+1)} 
$$

Now $\gamma_n$ converges as an increasing bounded from above sequence.

Comment: thank you @Sasha but in the steps when you write $\gamma_{n}$ is $\{\gamma_{n}\}$?

Comment: and, with this the proof is done isn't? :)

Comment: thank you, and another question, are you using some of the test of series, or only algebra of ontegrals ?

Comment: Why can I assume 0⩽t⩽1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\gamma_{n}-\gamma_{n+1}=[H_n-\ln n]-[H_{n+1}-\ln (n+1)]=\ln(n+1)-\ln n-\frac{1}{n+1}$

where $H_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$ and

$\ln n -\ln(n+1)=\frac{1}{c}>\frac{1}{n+1}$ for some $c\in(n,n+1)$,

$\hspace{.2 in}\gamma_n-\gamma_{n+1}>0$ and therefore $(\gamma_n)$ is a decreasing sequence.

Since $H_n>\int_1^{n+1}\frac{1}{x} dx=\ln(n+1)>\ln n$,

$\hspace{.2 in}\gamma_n=H_n-\ln n>0$ for all n.

Therefore $(\gamma_n)$ converges since it is a decreasing sequence which is bounded below.

Comment: The prove below says increasing ?

Comment: who is $H_{n}$?

Comment: I will edit my answer to indicate this; notice that $\gamma_1=1$ and $\gamma_2=\frac{3}{2}-\ln 2<1$.

Comment: Can you explain me this step lnn−ln(n+1)=1c>1n+1 for some c∈(n,n+1),

Comment: And who is right decraesing or increasing ?

Comment: How can you justificate this step lnn−ln(n+1)=1c>1n+1 for some c∈(n,n+1),

Comment: In this step, I am using the Mean Value Theorem for $\ln x$ on $(n,n+1)$; but you can also use $\ln(n+1)-\ln n=\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{1}{x} dx>\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: Ok then the othe answer is wrong? or what happened?, with both we are done, What I should do?

Comment: I would suggest calculating some values of $\gamma_n$ to check to see if it is increasing or decreasing.

Comment: Ok let me do it, give 5 min, I will tell you :)

Comment: is decreasing because  the 2nd and 3rd terms are 0.8 and 0.7 :)

Comment: and the 4th one is 0.6970389722

Comment: then you are right :), and this is the complete proof :) thank you a lot